# Sencha touch app generate issue in Mac OS

Tags: macos, sencha-touch-2

I am working start on sencha touch.I have mac os.I have download sencha-touch-2.2.1-commercial.zip and SenchaCmd-3.1.2.342-osx. I have extract and download both of pkg.Now when I  try to generate app using following command its gives errors.Please any body help me to resolve these issue.

Thanks :)

> ithands:~ mohitb$ sencha generate app MyApp ../MyApp
>
> Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] init-plugin:
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] -before-generate-workspace:
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] init-properties:
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] init-sencha-command:
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] init:
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] generate-workspace-impl:
>
> [INF]      [echo] generating into /Users/mohitb/../MyApp from
>   /Users/mohitb/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/templates/workspace
>
> [INF]     [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/MyApp/packages
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] copy-framework-to-workspace-impl:
>
> [INF] [propertyfile] Updating property file:
>   /Users/MyApp/.sencha/workspace/sencha.cfg
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] copy-framework-to-workspace:
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] generate-workspace:
>
> [INF]
>
> [INF] -after-generate-workspace:
>
> [ERR] Unable to locate 'framework.dir' property from sencha.cfg
>
> [ERR] Please ensure this command was executed from a valid framework
>   directory
>
> [ERR] Non-framework directory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the command from your sencha touch framework location, not from your workspace. (*/Users/mohitb/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/templates/workspace*)

> > Please ensure this command was executed from a valid framework
> >     directory.

Go to the **touch-2.2.1** in your **sencha-touch-2.2.1** folder and then use the generate command:

```
 sencha generate app [options] name \path
```

Comment: Yes! Took me so long to realize. Generate the app from within the touch-2.2.1 folder. Don't be a dummy like me!

Comment: Docs are sooooo bad for this. They say to use Sencha CMD for this - even though THIS IS THE WAY!

Comment: After a long, long marathon, it worked with you answer @MicRO. Thanks!